# Is it possible to write WORD Macro to search for a specific prefix and add it to the table with the section number where it was found

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

If possible, to write a Macro that will search for a prefix "SRS" in a WORD table and copy the prefix "SRS" with the number (SRS-1667) and the Section number with Name (1.1 Patient Search) in a table created at the end of the document?

Search for the string
[image]

The table will look like this

Final results

[image]

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, but SO is not a code writing service. Please take time to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What does the document being searched look like?